# Limiting User to One Decimal Point UILabel Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

So, if you read the question then you know the problem. I have read over a load of other articles about one decimal but all of them use this textfield thingy. I'm using a UILabel and have no idea how to only make one decimal point appear. Here is some of my code.

```
 @IBOutlet weak var Screen: UILabel!
var firstNumber = Float()
var secondNumber = Float()
var result = Float()
var operation = ""
var isTypingNumber = false
var dotString = "."

    @IBAction func Dot(sender: AnyObject) {
    let dot = sender.currentTitle
    Screen.text = Screen.text! + dot!!
}
```

I think I have provided enough code to fix the problem. The problem is I can enter 8.22.197.161... or as many decimals as the label can fit. I want it to stop putting more decimals after validating that there is only 1. I'm a pretty beginner noob at this stuff so any help will be appreciated as I have been breaking my head over this for the last couple days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, **if** there is no dot in the string, **then** you want to append a dot. Swift has something called an “if statement” that helps a lot:

```
if let text = Screen.text {
    if !text.containsString(".") {
        Screen.text = text + "."
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew about if statements :) I tried them too! I never knew the middle piece !text.containsString("."). Thank you sir and sorry for asking such a dumb question